# AJAX Uncaught reference error, unclear why?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I am in the process of converting my existing standard JS ajax functions to jQuery. So far I have converted all but one successfully, which seems to be causing an uncaught reference error.

For my add URL feature, I have a button which triggers this ajax function:

```
function showAdd(str)
    {
    document.getElementById("content01").innerHTML="";
    if (str=="")
    {
    document.getElementById("content01").innerHTML="";
    return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("content01").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "";
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","addUrlForm.php?addUrl="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The ajax directs to a html form echoed from php (I wont include as I know this isn't causing the issue). The form action directs to my insert ajax function here:

```
function insert() 
{
    var name= encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value);
    var releaseTime = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('releaseTime').value);
    var releaseDay = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('releaseDay').value);
    var category = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('category').value);
    var genre = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('genre').value);
    var url= encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('url').value);

    xmlhttp.open('get', 'addUrl.php?name='+name+'& releaseTime=' +releaseTime+'& releaseDay=' +releaseDay+'& category=' +category+'& genre=' +genre+'& url=' +url);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = urlRefresh;
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Processing Request. Please wait a moment...";
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    return;
}
```

And from this function the data goes to an insert statement and ends up in the DB. As it is the code above is working. When I change the SHOWADD ajax function to jQuery:

```
function showAdd(str)   {
    $('#response').html('loading...');         
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "addUrlForm.php",   
           data: "addUrl=" + str,                                        
           success: function(msg)   {
               $('#response').empty();
               $('#content01').html(msg).show();
           },
           error: function () {
               alert('error');
        }           
    });
};
```

Its spitting out the uncaught reference error. I know this isn't a huge error but if another peer of eyes could take a look and see what I missed that would be helpful. Thanks.

error reads: "Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined" on line 105:

`"xmlhttp.open('get', 'addUrl.php?name='+name+'& releaseTime=' +releaseTime+'& releaseDay=' +releaseDay+'& category=' +category+'& genre=' +genre+'& url=' +url);"`

Comment: What is the "exact" text of the error message and what line is it on?  And, I hate to ask the obvious question - is jQuery included in your page?

Comment: Hi, error reads: "Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined" on line 105: "xmlhttp.open('get', 'addUrl.php?name='+name+'& releaseTime=' +releaseTime+'& releaseDay=' +releaseDay+'& category=' +category+'& genre=' +genre+'& url=' +url);". jQuery is included on index.html page, all my JS functions are in a seperate JS file. All other functions are working, this is the only one with an error.

Comment: I put the error into your question where it's a lot more readable and useful to anyone else reading your question.  Multi-line things are not readable in comments.  I also wrote an answer since the specific error provides the clue as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switched to the 2nd `showAdd()` function, it does not initialize the `xmlhttp` object like the 1st `showAdd()` function did, but your `insert()` function is still trying to use xmlhttp, but since it is not defined, it causes an error.

Probably the best thing is to switch the `insert()` function over to use jQuery also so none of your code is trying to use the `xmlhttp` variable.

Comment: Thanks, ill get onto this now.

Comment: Hi, I converted the insert function to jQuery and everything is running. Thanks for the assist.